# Visual Studio Setup Project: Install Service Executable Marked as Hidden, System

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-services, installation, windows-installer

I'm using a Visual Studio 2010 'Setup Project' to install my C# Windows Service application.

I want to mark the installed service executable as `hidden` and `system` in the file properties, like so:

[image: Hidden and system properties set to true]

I've added custom actions to install the service as per **[this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169)**, but when I run the created MSI installer file, I get the following error message during installation:

> Error 1001. Exception occurred while initializing the installation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\path\to\my\service.exe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I checked the install location and the service executable *was* there marked as `hidden` and `system`, so I can only assume that the service installation is failing because of those attributes.

**How can I make the installer install the service executable, mark it as `hidden` and `system`, and install the Windows Service *successfully*?**

Surely this wouldn't be impossible if Visual Studio *allows* you to set files in the project as `hidden` and `system`?